# jquery + cross domain + ajax + webservice call

Tags: jquery, ajax

My webservice url is http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx

and the operation is GetCitiesByCountry

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?op=GetCitiesByCountry",
             data: "{'CountryName':'" + user + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (msg, status) {
                alert("successful");
                console.log(msg.d);
            },
            error: function (msg, status) {
                alert("failure");
                console.log("failure");
                console.log(msg);
                $('#myplace').html("The status is " + status + " with msg= " + msg + " .<br />" + msg.statusText + " .<br />" + msg.responseText + " .<br />" + msg.status);
            }
        });
```

but i am getting the following error.

```
The status is parsererror with msg= [object Object] .
success .
undefined .
200
```

when i put "india" as as the input.

How to solve this issue..thanks in advance

Comment: You can't POST with JSONP, and furthermore you can't POST cross-domain without implementing CORS which doesn't work in oldie

Comment: how to implement cors? how to check whether the service is jsonp or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url which i was using to get the jsonp is not actually returning the json response.
Thanks @SLaks

[Click here](http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo)
This url returns the json if somebody wants to try.

Comment: how did you make it return a JSON response then what is the relation between the link in your answer and your web service link